# How are the values of knots in MARS calculated?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, nonlinear-regression, mars

I'm wondering how the MARS algorithm decides on the specific values for the knots which are included in the hinge functions. Thank you very much.

Comment: Read the original paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176347963 .  Various implementations over the years have their own tweaks.  You can also look at "Restructuring Forward Step of MARS Algorithm Using a New Knot
Selection Procedure Based on a Mapping Approach" https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiO5ozP8afMAhVDFz4KHVzzAXIQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsc.iam.metu.edu.tr%2FiamWarehouse%2Fiam_Bibliography%2Fweb%2Findex.php%2Fattachments%2Fsingle%2F227&usg=AFQjCNH6ls0JaHkicPGBYdlESbQXRKxb3Q&sig2=GZSQ7e5MpsPlSzM1vGYnGw

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I can't find a version of the second paper that isn't behind a paywall. Is there any other literature on this subject?

Comment: First paper, http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176347963 is the original in the "field" and it's free for everyone "Full-text: Open access"  pdf is directly at http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176347963 .  Yes, 2nd link is behind a paywall now - I think I provided a link which wasn't behind a paywall, but that link is no longer valid. I don't have it myself.